# How to bucket the range of values from a column and count how many values fall into each interval in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I bucket the range of values(divide the entire range of values into a series of intervals) then count how many values fall into each interval.

I have a spark DataFrame with few numeric columns. In each column, I want to bucket the range of values then count how many values fall into each interval.

Comment: Providing a [mcve] will probably help answering this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scala Bucketizer.  There's a good example here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer

After you use the bucketizer you have a dataframe with a bucket index (i.e index 1, 2, and 3 might correspond to values 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, respectively).  You can do a .groupBy and .agg (or use SQL) to get a count of records in each index group).